# Nothing Happening When Entering Input and Pressing Enter C# on VSCode

Tags: c#, input, numbers

I've used other programming languages before, but I am learning C# and having some issues with getting the program to continue to the next input. I started from the beginning knocking out some simple exercises getting used to the language and VSCode as I have only ever used other IDE's before.

On this simple program when I hit "run and debug", it will ask me for the first number to input. I enter it on the debug console and hit enter. It doesn't go to the next input. I have the code exactly as they posted it on the site. If I switch `Console.WriteLine(); to Console.Write();` it is even worse as the input text never shows. I feel so dumb right now if it's something simple.

```
using System;
public class Exercise5
{
       public static void Main(string[] args)
         {
            int number1, number2, temp;
            Console.Write("\nInput the First Number : ");
            number1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("\nInput the Second Number : ");
            number2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            temp = number1;
            number1 = number2;
            number2 = temp;
            Console.Write("\nAfter Swapping : ");
            Console.Write("\nFirst Number : "+number1);
            Console.Write("\nSecond Number : "+number2);
            Console.Read();
        }
}
```

I tried getting it to read in two numbers and swap them. I could only ever get it to read in the first number and then after hitting enter, nothing happens but blank lines and I have to stop debugging to end the program.